# Stuck with this NT problem!

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that there exist a sequence of 2002 consecutive positive integers containing exactly 150 primes. (You may use the fact there are 168 primes $<1000$ ..
Actually, i came to know this from one of my senior,he asked me to solve it using Pigeon hole principle but making several attempts i think PHP doesn't work here!

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Please read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960 and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you edit your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: THanks for the information, i am really sorry for my ignorance :)

Answer (score 2):

Start with the sequence $1, 2, 3, \ldots, 2002$. It contains more than $150$ primes. Then throw away $1$ and add $2003$. Then throw away $2$ and add $2004$. Make the sequence crawl forward like a snake. With each step the number of primes in the sequence changes by at most 1. So, if you can prove that at some point the sequence will contain less than 150 primes, it will follow that at some point before that it contained exactly 150 primes.

So now the problem stands like this: prove that there exists a sequence of $2002$ consecutive positive integers containing *less than* 150 primes. This is a very rough statement, there should be a zillion ways to prove it. For instance, if you explicitly find two consecutive primes more than $2000$ units apart, you are done. Or you can use an analytic result such as [Chebyshev's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevsTheorem.html). Or you can invent some trick. Really, at this point the possibilities are countless.

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: There are definitely sequences of 2002 consecutive positive integers such that more than 150 of them are primes (you are given one). There are definitely sequences of 2002 consecutive positive integers such that fewer than 150 of them are primes (the Chinese Remainder Theorem can help you find some of the bigger ones).

Hint 2: This sounds like the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) but we are not dealing with continuous functions here. Can you postulate the equivalent theorem here? What does "continuous enough" mean for integer sequences? What sequence do you have with that property?